# updating deprecated centos version?

Tags: centos, yum

I just rebooted an old Centos VM I have:
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

when I try to do a:
    sudo yum update

all the mirrors return 404 - not found.
I have tried in my browser and indeed the links don't exist anymore. How can I update my centos and get yum working again?

Comment: // , Can you return any of the _actual_ output that you saw, here, and improve the grammar and style?

Answer (score 7):

I needed to run:

```
yum clean all
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=base update
yum update
```

and that cleaned everything up and cleared the 404 errors